# Background transfer in watchos2

Tags: swift, watchos-2

I tried to use transferUserInfo for sharing data between iPhone and Apple Watch in background.
But it sharing data only when you open the app. Is it possible to transfer data instantly?

(I need to start timer on iPhone when I started it on the Apple Watch at the same time)

Sorry, if my English is bad :( Thanks!

Comment: transferUserInfo doesn't transfer data instantly. Instead transferUserInfo sends data when the system determines a good time to send it. So in your case since you opened the app the system determined that it's a good time to transfer data so it got transferred.

Comment: Thanks, @Harish , so, could you tell me what I need to use in my case, please?

Comment: You would need to use Interactive Messaging. However, there are a couple of requirements that must be fulfilled for Interactive Messaging to work such as it must be reachable. For more details I would recommend watching this WWDC Video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/713/. It explains it in detail and he starts talking about interactive messaging at around 28:53.